# What is the best way to access an element through a data-attribute whose value is an object (JSON)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, custom-data-attribute

Say I have the following element:

```html
<div class='selector' data-object='{"primary_key":123, "foreign_key":456}'></div>
```

If I run the following, I can see the object in the console.

```
console.log($('.selector').data('object'));
```

I can even access data like any other object.

```
console.log($('selector').data('object').primary_key); //returns 123
```

Is there a way to select this element based on data in this attribute? The following does not work.

```
$('.selector[data-object.foreign_key=456]');
```

I can loop over all instances of the selector

```js
var foreign_key = 456;
$('.selector').each(function () {
  if ($(this).data('object').foreign_key == foreign_key) {
    // do something
  }
});
```

but this seems inefficient. Is there a better way to do this? Is this loop actually slower than using a selector?

Comment: Will this work for you: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Comment: I was unable to reproduce your results, did you mean your html was like `data-object='{"primary_key":123, "foreign_key":456}'`

Comment: Yes! Very sorry, thank you. Editing my original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [the contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

```
var key_var = 456;
$(".selector[data-object*='foreign_key:" + key_var + "']");
```

I think that you may gain a little speed here over the loop in your example because in your example jQuery is JSON parsing the value of the attribute. In this case it's most likely using the JS native `string.indexOf()`. The potential downside here would be that formatting will be very important. If you end up with an extra space character between the colon and the key value, the `*=` will break.

Another potential downside is that the above will also match the following:

```
<div class='selector' data-object="{primary_key:123, foreign_key:4562}"></div>
```

The key is clearly different but will still match the pattern. You can include the closing bracket `}` in the matching string:

```
$(".selector[data-object*='foreign_key:" + key_var + "}']");
```

But then again, formatting becomes a key issue. A hybrid approach could be taken:

```
var results = $(".selector[data-object*='" + foreign_key + "']").filter(function () {
    return ($(this).data('object').foreign_key == foreign_key)
});
```

This will narrow the result to only elements that have the number sequence then make sure it is the exact value with the filter.

Comment: Great ideas. Note that the last example using `filter` requires that the value be a validly formatted object and not simply a string (as mentioned by Musa): `{"primary_key":123,"foreign_key":456}`. Demonstrated here: [working](http://jsfiddle.net/r4cb0xu4/2/) vs [not working](http://jsfiddle.net/r4cb0xu4/3/).

Comment: @showdev certainly. I actually did not realize that jQuery would sort of "automatically" parse JSON data in an attribute. In any route that the OP takes here, proper and consistent formatting will be important.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you.

Comment: @jwatts1980 I've been using php's json_encode function, and was too lazy when typing this post up to check for correct formatting. Hopefully formatting won't give me too much trouble.

Comment: @user3630824 You're welcome. As was mentioned a in other comments, the parameter names in the JSON should have quotes around them. And since the `*=` is matching the string value, make sure to include the quotes if they are going to be apart of your pattern. As with most scripting languages, it will likely take a bit of trial and error to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

With a "contains" attribute selector.

`$('selector[data-object*="foreign_key:456"]')`